# How to add data to JSONObject before going to use HttpPost request?

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I have a json data like below ::

```
{

     "lastName":"sadfsdf",
       "email":"acb@bbc.com",
       "gender":"male",
       "workids":[0,0],
       "roleId":102
}
```

for workids parameter i used ArrayList of params.

```
{
List<Integer> ll = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ll.add(100);
ll.add(102);
}
```

I added params to json object like this

```
{

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    json.put("lastName", "bbdddb");
    json.put("email","abc@bbc.com");
    json.put("gender","male");
    json.put("secGameIds",ll);
    json.put("roleId",secGame);
}
```

This was the post request i made.

```
{

     HttpPost post = new HttpPost(uri);
     post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
     post.setEntity(new StringEntity(json.toString(), "UTF-8"));
     DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
     HttpResponse httpresponse = client.execute(post);
    }
```

When i try to run this program  `{json.put("secGameIds",ll);}` due to this parameter `json.toString()` sending as string instead of Integer List. 
How can i make that parameter as Integer List only when making the request?

Thanks & Regards.

Comment: Use should probably be using a JSONArray instead of adding an Arraylist to the JsonObject

Comment: And can you clarify "json.toString() sending as string instead of Integer List."? Of course it sends as a string, you explicitly toString-d the JSON object, not the integer list itself

Answer (score 0):

Use jsonschema2pojo.org service to generate java class, which can be parsed to/from JSON by using GSON library. 
In JSON all data is sent as String, not Integer, it is parsed on receipt.
As you can see, list in POJO below is list of Integer, even though JSON has strings. Gson parses strings into integers.
Your class wil look like (it is a good practice):

```
-----------------------------------com.example.User.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
public class User {

@SerializedName("lastName")
@Expose
private String lastName;
@SerializedName("email")
@Expose
private String email;
@SerializedName("gender")
@Expose
private String gender;
@SerializedName("workids")
@Expose
private List<Integer> workids = new ArrayList<Integer>();
@SerializedName("roleId")
@Expose
private Integer roleId;

/**
* 
* @return
* The lastName
*/
public String getLastName() {
return lastName;
}

/**
* 
* @param lastName
* The lastName
*/
public void setLastName(String lastName) {
this.lastName = lastName;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The email
*/
public String getEmail() {
return email;
}

/**
* 
* @param email
* The email
*/
public void setEmail(String email) {
this.email = email;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The gender
*/
public String getGender() {
return gender;
}

/**
* 
* @param gender
* The gender
*/
public void setGender(String gender) {
this.gender = gender;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The workids
*/
public List<Integer> getWorkids() {
return workids;
}

/**
* 
* @param workids
* The workids
*/
public void setWorkids(List<Integer> workids) {
this.workids = workids;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The roleId
*/
public Integer getRoleId() {
return roleId;
}

/**
* 
* @param roleId
* The roleId
*/
public void setRoleId(Integer roleId) {
this.roleId = roleId;
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks for that...
How to add these variables to object and How can i make a post request to my url now?

Thanks and regards

Comment: You should use Retrofit library for REST, see tutorial https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Consuming-APIs-with-Retrofit

Answer (score 0):

What if you try like below:

```
private void executeNetworkOperation(String jsonData) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

    urlConnection = null;

    try {
        URL connectionUrl = new URL(url);
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connectionUrl.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(timeoutConnection);
        urlConnection.setReadTimeout(timeoutRead);
        urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/json");

        OutputStream outputStream = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
        outputStream.write(jsonData.getBytes());
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();


        InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();

    } catch (MalformedURLException e){
        AppUtils.showLog(TAG, e.getMessage(), 2);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        AppUtils.showLog(TAG, e.getMessage(), 2);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        AppUtils.showLog(TAG, e.getMessage(), 2);
    }finally {
        if(null != urlConnection) {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you mean jsonData variable is my json data.

Comment: Yes. I tried like this, and its working perfectly. I used jsonData for Signup procedure.